# Differentiation w/ a Cone and Cylinder

Tags: calculus, derivatives, word-problem

I am trying to solve the following problem:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pibMkkuY_1Onve8WzUBRhxF7_qZlgLyiFAOpjTEnjcI/edit?usp=sharing

This is my attempt at solving:

Given: Cone: r=2cm.; h=5cm.; dh/dt = 3cm/s @ the point of submersion;
       Cylinder: r=7cm.; h = L <--- Depth of the Water.

Unknown: dL/dt @ the point of submersion

I started off by stating that the volume of the water in the cylinder at the point of submersion is equal to the volume of the water - (pi)(r^2)(L) minus the volume of the cone - (pi/3)(r^2)(h).

After substituting the given values, I found that the volume of the cylinder is 49pi(L) - (pi/3)(h). When I take the derivative of both in respect to t on both sides, I found that the derivative of volume is equal to 0 because it's rate of change is constant throughout the point of submersion. This results in: 49pi(dL/dt) = (pi/3)(dh/dt). By using the given dh/dt, I found that the depth of the water is increasing at 1/49 cm/s at the point of submersion.

Question:

Is my setup correct, and is my solution sound? Is the overall height of the cylinder important to consider in solving this problem?

Comment: 'After substituting the given values, I found that the volume of the cylinder is 49pi(L) - (pi/3)(h)'. - How did you get this may I ask?

Comment: I stated that V = (pi)(r^2)(L) - (pi/3)(r^2)(h), or the volume of the water in the cylinder is equal to the volume of the water in the cylinder minus the volume of the cone. The reason I set these two expressions together is because the height of the water in the cylinder will change (L) due to the addition of the cone. I substituted the given values for each respective volume.

Comment: using your V = (pi)(R^2)(L) - (pi/3)(r^2)(h), I know that the first R is constant 7, but the second r is a variable that changes as the cone submerges. Using similar triangles, I know that 2/5 = r/h therefore r = 0.4h. therefore volume is actually 49pi(L) - (pi/3)(0.16)(h^3). I'm sure you will get a different answer now.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!